# Show next field hover toggle button

Tags: php, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my ionic app i used a toggle button. I want to show next field whenever i on toggle. and hide that field when i off the toggle

page.ts

```
onClickToggle()

pass: any = false;

{

  this.pass = true;

}
```

page.html

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-input type="readonly" readonly>Remind me at a location
  </ion-input>
  <ion-toggle color="danger" (click)="onClickToggle()">
  </ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
<div *ngIf="pass == true">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Location
    </ion-label>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright">
    </ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="isActive" (ionChange)="toggleInput()"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
  <IonInput placeholder="Enter Input" *ngIf="isActive"></IonInput>


 isActive: boolean = false;
 toggleInput() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem, you toggle button switch your value

> this.pass

to TRUE or FALSE;

So on your INPUT in your HTML code you put something like this:

```
<input *ngIf="this.pass"> YOUR INPUT YOU WANT TO SHOW/HIDE </input>
```

If this solve your problem write it as solved :)